# Vue.js 2 + ckeditor5 with mention plugin

Tags: vuejs2, ckeditor5

All works, except mentions

main vue.js app code snippet

```
<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="innerValue" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
...
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';
...
data: () => {
    return {
        innerValue: null,
        editor: ClassicEditor,
        editorConfig: {
            toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '|', 'undo'],
            mention: {
                feeds: [
                    {
                        marker: '@',
                        feed: ['@Barney', '@Lily', '@Marshall', '@Robin', '@Ted'],
                        minimumCharacters: 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    }
},
```

main app dependencies

```
...
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.3",
  "ckeditor5-custom-build": "0.0.6",
...
```

ckeditor5-custom-build package.json code snippet

```
  "name": "ckeditor5-custom-build",
  "author": "CKSource",
  "description": "A custom CKEditor 5 build made by the CKEditor 5 online builder.",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "main": "./build/ckeditor.js",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention": "^16.0.0",
    ...
```

official guide https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html